# How to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to + \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

So I have another question on limits. In this case the limit is:

$$\lim_{x\to + \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}$$

I tried to transform it into
$$
\lim_{x\to + \infty}  \frac{x^2+4}{x^2}
$$
because I wanted to solve it by factoring but I checked the graph of both and they are different..

I'm stuck here cause my idea doesn't work and I don't know how to solve it!
Could someone be so kind to help me? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Though note that you're still getting the same answer if you take the positive square root of the limit you're getting in your squared expression.

Comment: Informally, as $x$ gets larger, the $4$ contributes less, percent-wise, to the value of $x^2+4$. So you can think of $\sqrt{x^2+4}$ as just a bit bigger than $x$, say $x + \delta$ where $\frac{\delta}{x}$ gets smaller as $x$ gets bigger. Then 
$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x} 
  \to \frac{x + \delta}{x} 
  \to 1 + \frac{\delta}{x}
  \to 1$.

Answer (score 10):

Factoring $x^2$ out of the expression under the root, you get : 
$$ \lim_{x\to + \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x} = \lim_{x\to + \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+4/x^2)}}{x} = \lim_{x\to + \infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{1+4/x^2}}{x}$$
Now, note that $x\to +\infty$ which means that $x>0$, thus :

$$\lim_{x\to + \infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{1+4/x^2}}{x}= \lim_{x\to + \infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1+4/x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to + \infty}\sqrt{1+4/x^2}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}x&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+4}{x^2}}\\&=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to+\infty}1+\frac4{x^2}}\\&=\sqrt{1}\\&=1.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $x>0$.

$1= \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x} \lt \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x} \lt$

$\dfrac{(x+2)}{x}= 1+ \dfrac{2}{x}.$

And the limit is?

Used: $x^2+4 \lt (x+2)^2$, for $x >0$.

Comment: Peter you don't bound to 1 in such way.

Comment: You're missing something on the RHS in the first inequality. I'm not sure if it was intentionally left blank as a hint :/

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x} \lt \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x} \lt \dfrac{(x+2)}{x}= 1+ \dfrac{2}{x}$

Comment: Thanks, gimusi,  I got it,  as frequently, I miss half the answer, my specialty:))).

Comment: You idea is very good Peter, complete the answer!

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks !!!! This time I admit, I copy . Happy New Year! Let's have a few interesting problems to solve.

Comment: @Tandon.Thanks ,now also bounded below.

Answer (score 2):

It occurred to me that the problem would be a lot easier if $\sqrt{x^2+4}$ was $\sqrt{x^2+4}-x$, So I came up with this.

\begin{align}
   \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}
   &= \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}-1\right) + 1 \\
   &=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}-x}{x} + 1 \\
   &=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)}{x(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)} + 1 \\
   &=\frac{4}{x(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)} + 1 \\
   &\to 1 \ \text{as} \ x \to \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous functuion, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^2}}}{x}=\sqrt{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)}=1$$